# Dropdown menu doesn't assign name to selection box to get it with $_POST[]

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with the POST method.

I have a dropdown menu with different tram stops and I have assigned a name to the dropdown menu within my form. On the next page I try to get the selected tram_stop but if I do `$POST_['NameOfSelectionBox]` I get nothing. Here's my code:

DROP DOWN MENU:

```
// list box select command
echo "<select name=$count value=''><option>Please choose desired stop. </option>";

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "1";
    echo '<option value='.$r['id'].'>'.$r['name_'].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>"; // Closing of list box
```

So `name = $count`, and `$count` is just a variable starting at 1 and going once for each new drop down menu I make, so in my understanding I should be able to get the selected value from the dropdown menu with

```
$_POST['1']
```

on my next webpage.
This doesn't work and with this code

```
if(($_POST['1'] == 0))
{
    echo "xyz";
}
```

I found out that is 0 even if something has been selected and submited.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I did the recommended step to fix the problem as I declared all of my variables before using them. No improvements unfortunately.

Furthermore I think he does recognize that the section field with `$_POST['1']`, but it's just 0.

**EDIT: SOLVED!** I had to change it to  `'<option value='.$r['name_'].'>'.$r['name_'].'</option>';`

So I don't get the id back which happend to be 0. Really dumb mistake. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is the value of `$count`? You should give your form fields more meaningful names, such as `"tram_stop"` and not leave it up to a variable. Any change to `$count` in the rendering script will cause it to fall out of sync with the form handling code. Also, it's probably safer to enclose your select attributes in double quotes, like: `echo "<select name=\"field_name\" ...`

Comment: Hello and thanks for the feedback! I'm doing this with a variable because this is in a google maps like webapp for a function to add a route of 2 to n stops. So I don't know how many of these dropdown menus I will have before  the user states how many he wants. Since I will have to keep working with the names I thought it's easiest to do with a count. 
And if that's safer I will use double quotes from now on, thanks!
Edit: oh and the value of count starts with 1 and goes up by one for each dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
echo "<select name=$count value=\"\"><option>Please choose desired stop. </option>"; // list box select command

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=".$r['id']." ";
if($_POST['count']==$r['name_']){ echo " selected ";}
echo ">".$r['name_']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
```

have fun

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sadly this gives me a weired error "undefined index count" that replaces all stops in the dropdown menu (so you can only select the error messages now hehe).

Comment: Try `$_POST["$count"]` instead of `$_POST['count']` - the latter is assuming there is a field called `count`, which in my understanding is not the case...

Comment: Then I am getting an "undefined offset" error within the dropdown menu for (instead of the entries).    $count=1    at that moment.